# AngularJS copying from clipboard [EXCEL]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have a problem with copying data from Excel. I created "**text field**" in excel and I put here some data e.g. "a". I copied the data from the text field and I tried pasting it to a `text-angular-toolbar` (like this http://textangular.com/), but nothing happened. When I pasted the data to a notepad and again copied from the notepad and paste it to the text-angular-field, it works. The problem doesn't occur when I paste the data to simple text field.

I tried view the content of clipboard in `hexaeditor`, but it looks good.
Any idea?

Comment: Try pasting the text only, like `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`

Comment: Thank you! It works, but is it possible to paste the text like ctrl+v?

Comment: I guess its not possible, excel copies its formatting too, that is the sequences and etc that would specifically work in excel's other cells too, that is why we need to paste only text with `ctrl+shhift+v`

Comment: Do i add an answer to this question from my above comment?

Comment: Yes. I have an idea to add "hotkeys" and mapping ctrl+v to ctrl+shift+v.

Comment: okay, if this works then its a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pasting the text only without the formatting, like `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`

Answer (score 0):

[CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has an option to automatically cleanup office-formatted content on paste.
This option seems to be activated by default on their online demo editor.
Try it, it should work.

There are plenty of Angularjs directive to wrap ckeditor, like [this one](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor)